# How can I implement double sigma in R

Tags: r

[image]

My first thought was using nested for loop.But some people recommend to me, in R programming, avoid nested for loop and find functional ways.

So I tried this way.
temp<-0
for (i in 1 :10000) temp<- temp
for (j in 1 :1000)
sum(temp)
But I think it's wrong
please solve this problem.

Comment: To enter code in a question or answer, plese set it as a block with 4 leading blanks.

Answer (score 0):

R is vectorized, so the inner loop would just be `sum(1:1000)^-i)`. Since you need to do this for each value of `i` between 1 and 10000, you can put this inside an `sapply` and sum the result:

```r
sum(sapply(seq(10000), function(i) sum((1:1000)^(-i))))
#> [1] 10007.48
```

Comment: IThanks for solving the problem.
I just solved this problem myself.
But I think the answer's different from yours.
Did I do anything wrong?                                                                                                          x <- 0
> for(i in 1:10000){
+   for(j in 1:1000){
+     x <- x + i^(-j)
+   }
+ }
> x
[1] 1009.788

Comment: @Allan, can you help me on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64756969/grouping-multiple-png-with-sub-headings-in-rmarkdown) question ?